# My new faucet has a warped cold water supply line nut

Tags: kitchen-sink

Is there a way to cut out the warped fitting and put a new one on? It's a very expensive faucet I can't return because I'm past the return window.

Comment: Picture? Manufacturer/model#?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. As @manassehkatz says, we'll need more info. In particular, adding a picture to your question would really help us.

Comment: If it's defective you may be able to use the warranty to get a replacement, rather than be limited by "return" - many high end faucets are 5 years or even lifetime on defects. Call the manufacturer.